# How to select all where the condition is null?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php code with a query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TDdb WHERE status = $status AND occupation =$occupation";
```

I am sending the values status and occupation with a client application to this php code.
This works when I send both status and occupation. But I want it to return rows if I just send status but not occupation also ( I mean no matter what the occupation is).

does anyone have any suggestions?
I would appreciate any help.

PS: I want to do it without if statement and just but changing the query

Comment: This seems too easy enough to confuse people

Comment: what do you mean "without if statement" and how do you expect to change the query without it?

Comment: obligatory warning regarding SQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Doing this without an if would be inefficient though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would create a base query and append conditions wherever you have them, like so:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM TDdb';
$conditions = array();
$args = array();

if ($action) {
    $conditions[] = 'status = :status';
    $args[':status'] = $status;
}

if ($occupation) {
    $conditions[] = 'occupation = :occupation';
    $args[':occupation'] = $occupation;
}

if ($conditions) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE ' . join(' AND ', $conditions);
}

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($args);
```

Comment: thanks jack. your idea helped a lot. finally I created something like this:

Comment: $query = 'SELECT * FROM TDdb';

if ($status) {
    $query = $query." WHERE status = '".$status."'";
}

if ($occupation) {
    $query = $query." AND occupation = '".$occupation."'";
}

Comment: @user2108800 That will not work if `$occupation` is defined but not `$status`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got a few good options for how to do it in SQL, or how to make the SQL string variable in PHP.

One reason to consider using an 'if' in the PHP code for the database access performance.

When you introduce an 'or' condition like that in SQL, you're not going to get index access. It is much harder for the database to determine what path it should take than for the PHP code because the SQL engine optimizes the query without knowing what the variable will resolve to at execution.

You already know in the PHP which version of the query you really want. This will perform better if you make that choice there.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you pass an occupation or a NULL value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TDdb 
WHERE  status = $status 
       AND ($occupation IS NULL OR occupation = $occupation)
```

Comment: that won't work, if $occupation is NULL then your query will look like this: `...WHERE  status = X AND ( IS NULL OR occupation = )`, you need to add the quotes

Comment: If the value is passed as a NULL this will work.  If the value is passed as an empty string you would need quotes.

Comment: both `$occupation = NULL;` and `$occupation = ""` won't work, `$occupation = "NULL";` will work but won't have the expected behavior

Comment: If a NULL value is passed (not an empty string, or a string = "NULL"), `$occupation IS NULL` will evaluate to true, and the OR clause will be ignored.

Comment: This produces a syntax error (at least on my mysql server version 5.5.13, maybe that's different with newer versions)

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM TDdb WHERE status = '$status' AND (occupation = '$occupation' OR occupation IS NULL)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the solution provided by @Tom and @Damien Legros, you may create two query strings one with occupation and one without occupation. Something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TDdb WHERE status = $status";
if ($occupation != "") { 
   /*When you have value for occupation*/
   $query .= " AND occupation =$occupation";
}
```

So in this case, data will be returned if you have only the status field. Secondly, please check if the status and occupation fields in table are varchar then you have to enclose them in single quotes (').

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for help. specially jack.
finally i created my query like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM TDdb';

if ($status) {
    $query = $query." WHERE status = '".$status."'";
}

if ($occupation) {
    $query = $query." AND occupation = '".$occupation."'";
}
```